# How to visualize partial derivatives of Dirac delta distributions?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, distribution-theory

Consider the characteristic function of $[0, \infty)^2$ (i.e. a function $u: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $u(x, y) = 1$ if $x \geq 0$, $y \geq 0$ and $u(x, y) = 0$ otherwise). I want to compute $\partial_x \partial_y u$, where the derivatives are *distributional*, to avoid blowup at jump discontinuities. Since $u$ projected onto the $y$-axis is just the Heaviside function,  $\partial_y u(x, y) = \delta_0(y)$ if $x \geq 0$ and $\partial_y u(x, y) = 0$ otherwise.

I visualize this $\partial_y u$ as a map which sends the plane to itself, except on the ray $\{(x, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \geq 0\}$, in which case all points are "mapped" to $+\infty$. The trouble is, this gives me no intuition how to approach the computation of its second derivative $\partial_x$. My best guess is that I should expect $\partial_x \partial_y u$ to be identically $0$ outside of the origin, where it is $+\infty$; i.e. that $\partial_x \partial_y u = \delta_0$. But this also feels like "cheating" somehow: I would expect $\delta_0$ to only be the derivative of a *finite* multiple of the Heaviside function, not of a distribution which is already infinite!

Is this method of approaching differentiation of distributions appropriate? If I bashed out convolutions of $C_0^\infty$ functions I could probably (dis?)prove that $\partial_x \partial_y u = \delta_0$, but I'd still feel unsure why it's true/false, because I don't know how to imagine the partial derivatives of a distribution.

Comment: Related Phys.SE question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161275/2451

Answer (score 1):

You have $u(x,y) = H(x) \otimes H(y)$ so 
$$\partial_x \partial_y u(x,y) = \partial_x H(x) \, \partial_y H(y) = \delta(x) \delta(y) = \delta(x,y).$$
(Here $x$ and $y$ should be viewed as placeholders rather than values.)

Comment: To visualize a distribution $T$ simply look at the sequence of $C^\infty$ functions $T \ast \phi_n$ with $\phi_n(x) = n^d \phi(nx), \phi \in C^\infty_c,\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \phi(x)dx = 1$ !

Comment: @reuns. Why did you put your comment under my answer? And isn't your answer like saying "To visualize $\mathbb R^4$ simply look at $\mathbb R^n$ and then take $n=4$"?

Comment: What do you mean with $\mathbb{R}^4$ ? It is like saying real numbers are limits of sequences of rationals. Do you realize $T \ast \phi_n \to T$ in the sense of distributions where $T \ast \phi_n$ is a sequence of $C^\infty$ functions, and $\partial^\alpha T = \lim_{n \to \infty} \partial^\alpha (T \ast \phi_n)$ ? Why do you refuse to explain distributions this way to those asking for an intuitive explanation ?

Comment: How do you visualize $T * \phi_n$ when you don't even know how to visualize $T$?

Comment: Here $T = \partial_x \partial_y u$ thus $T \ast \phi_n = \partial_x \partial_y \Phi_n$ where $\Phi_n = u \ast \phi_n$ is just a smoothed version of $u(x,y) = 1_{x \ge 0, y \ge 0}$

Comment: But if you don't have any visualization of $u$, how could you have a visualization of $u * \phi_n$? It's like saying that to visualize you, I should just visualize a mix of your parents. But I don't know how they look!

Comment: ?? It is really like saying a real number has a decimal expansion, ie. is a limit of a sequence of rationals, and that's the way you'd explain real numbers  to most people.

Comment: I *do not* say that distributions can not be visualized as sequences of functions. I do not even say that it is wrong to do it.

Comment: @md2perpe "But if you don't have any visualization of $u$". Reuns said $u = 1_{x \ge 0, y \ge 0}$, which is easy to visualize. I understand if you take issue with what he is saying for general distributions, but I really don't understand your comments. He explicitly said what $u$ is.

Comment: @mathworker21. The special case $u = 1_{x \ge 0, y \ge 0}$ is easy to visualize directly. But look at his first comment "To visualize a distribution $T$ simply look at .../ $T * \phi_n$ /.../". If you are just given a distribution and don't understand it, how should should you visualize its convolution with a mollifier?

Comment: @md2perpe "I understand if you take issue with what he is saying for general distributions". in any event, it seems he has provided a good answer to the OP's question